# How to Partition HD to install windows?

Tags: partitioning, windows-7

I'd like to install win 7 along with kubuntu.

Could anyone please tell me how should I partition the HD?

Shall I partition SDA1 or 3?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would resize `/dev/sda3`, and use the newly created partition.  Make sure that you boot from the Ubuntu live/Bootable media, and use gparted to resize that partition.

Now from the image I can see that you have labeled `/dev/sda3` as Data.  If you like to use the whole partition, I would backup that data, and then use the whole partition.

**Warning:**  When dealing with partitions anything can go wrong, so make sure that you have a current backup of all your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response Mitch, since devsda 3 is not a linux partition can't I just unmount it and resize wihout using the live cd?

Comment: Yes you can.  But make sure that you backup the data on it, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be storing your data and operating systems on separate partitions I would suggest taking space from sda1. I would speculate you may need the data space in the future, but will probably never use all the OS space even with 2 operating systems unless you install lots of large programs (games often being a good example of space eaters). Also by not editing your data partition you reduce the likely hood of loosing it if your shrinking proceedure fails. It boils down to personal preference.

1. To shrink a partition in Gparted right click on it and choose "Resize/Move". This will need to be done from a livecd, because you cannot shrink the partition while running Ubuntu on it.
2. Change the size to what you want. DO NOT MOVE THE PARTITION THOUGH. Apply the change using the checkmark at the top of Gparted.
3. Right click on the free space and choose "New". Then create a new partition for Windows (choose NTFS as the format type if you aren't sure what you want). Again click on the checkmark to apply the change.

Comment: Thanks unorthodox grammar,

I think that option would fit most my needs, having two Os in hte same partition.

I believe i should boot kubuntu with the live cd correct?

Comment: Yes, you will need to do the partitioning from a livecd.

Comment: You will be shrinking the OS partition, and creating a new one in the freed space. Each OS will be on it's own partition.

Comment: Ok i've partitioned as follow, see screenshot, now I should be fine rebooting with win on a usb stick and installing it on SDA4 hope? 

http://imgur.com/UaLGZYM

Comment: It looks good .